# Struts2 + Rest Plugin: strange behavior when setting properties in action class

Tags: rest, struts2

I'm facing a strange behavior with struts2 using the rest plugin. Strange because in the Web Application I've already done, everything is working fine.

Well, I have a popup jsp with a post form. This form action url calls correctly the create method of a controller.

```
<form name="gestioneUtenteForm" action="../credenziali" method="post">
           <input type="hidden" name="idModifica" id="idUtente" value="<%=request.getParameter("idModifica") %>" />
            <div>
                <label>Nome Completo</label>
                <input type="text" name="nomeUtente" id="nomeUtente" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Login</label>
                <input type="text" name="loginUtente" id="loginUtente" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Conferma Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="confermaPassword" id="confermaPassword" />
            </div>
            <!-- ... OTHER FIELDS ... -->

        <div><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Registra" /></div>
    </form>
```

My problem is that not all property values of the controller are being setted from post's parameters. I mean, with firebug I see that all parameters are being posted and if I get them in the controller with calls like request.getParameter("something"), I'm getting all the values. If I try to get parameters from controller's properties with their getters, I get something correctly but something else with null values. In the specific:

```
private String nomeUtente;
private String loginUtente;
private String password;
... Other Properties ....


public String getNomeUtente() {
    return nomeUtente;
}

public void setNomeUtente(String nomeUtente) {
    this.nomeUtente = nomeUtente;
}

public String getLoginUtente() {
    return loginUtente;
}

public void setLoginUtente(String loginUtente) {
    this.loginUtente = loginUtente;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

... Other Setters & Getters ...



public HttpHeaders create() {
    GestioneUtenteService.creaUtente(nomeUtente, loginUtente, password,
            mailUtente, telUtente, scadenzaReg, scadenzaPwd, ruoloUtente);

    if (Integer.valueOf(ruoloUtente) == Constants.NUM_RUOLO_ADMIN_GENERALE)
        return new DefaultHttpHeaders("accesso").disableCaching();

    return index();
}
```

I have that loginUtente has correct values, like other properties. BUT... nomeUtente and password are null. While if I call:

```
public HttpHeaders create() {

    HttpServletRequest request = getServletRequest();
    nomeUtente = request.getParameter("nomeUtente");
    loginUtente = request.getParameter("loginUtente");
    password = request.getParameter("password");
    mailUtente = request.getParameter("mailUtente");
    telUtente = request.getParameter("telUtente");
    scadenzaReg = request.getParameter("scadenzaReg");
    scadenzaPwd = request.getParameter("scadenzaPwd");
    ruoloUtente = request.getParameter("ruoloUtente");

    logger.info("Creazione utente");
    GestioneUtenteService.creaUtente(nomeUtente, loginUtente, password,
            mailUtente, telUtente, scadenzaReg, scadenzaPwd, ruoloUtente);

    if (Integer.valueOf(ruoloUtente) == Constants.NUM_RUOLO_ADMIN_GENERALE)
        return new DefaultHttpHeaders("accesso").disableCaching();

    return index();
}
```

as I said before, I'm getting all values...nomeUtente and password included, because everything is being posted.
Again with the Web Application everything is working and the controller's properties are all correctly setted.

Where's the problem?

Comment: a bit hard to say about what is going wrong here? do you have any kind of validation(struts2 validator) in place for your fields? just use logger level as `INFO` to see what is going wrong, for me it seems either there is some errors OGNL facing which preventing it from setting values to respected fields

Comment: No I'm not using validators of any kind, or at least I have setted no one of these. And you're right there's something wrong with OGNL, because when i invoke a put method (passing _method=PUT as form parameter), logger says I'm having problem with OGNL

Comment: are you posting JSON or other content-type? try posting ASCII character to verify that it is not an encoding error

Comment: I solved my problem. It was that my implementation of "public Object getModel()" method (required to implement an interface related to the rest plugin) was returning a List of my model objects (call it Products), but if that list was null, it was returning a new SINGLE INSTANCE of Products. I changed it in returning my List of Products or, if null, a new LIST of Products